# Access a firebird embedded database using squirrel

Tags: firebird, squirrel-sql, firebird-embedded

I am using an application that apparently uses Firebird as database.

I believe this because in the app directory, I found the files firebird.conf and firebird.msg. The data file is called database.cdb.

I'm trying to access this file directly, without going through the application. Can anyone suggest me a good way to do this?

I'm trying to use the SQuirrel SQL, but so far without success (I'm not able to build a proper connection string).

I'm using a windows SO. I checked services/process and wasn't able to find anyone that suggests that Firebird is running.

Comment: is this java, then? Please tag appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install a [Firebird Server](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/) and then use a Firebird admin tool like [Flame Robin](http://www.flamerobin.org/) to access the database. You need to make sure that the application is not running, because most likely it is using Firebird embedded (which means that database server is running as part of the application, and the database file will then be opened exclusively by the application).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be able to use the [Jaybird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-devel-status/) JDBC provider.

Comment: This was my prefered solution, but I was not able to construct a connection string successfully. I was trying something like jdbc:firebirdsql:embedded:c:\database.cdb, but I was receiving some exceptions. So I used the approach described by Mark, and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use Jaybird in combination with embedded, you will need to add the [Firebird embedded files](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/) and the jaybird21.dll in the root of your Squirrel installation (or on the library path, or normal path). Otherwise Jaybird will be unable to locate the required files. If you have Firebird server installed, you can use jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/C:/database.cdb as URL

Answer (score 0):

Install Firebird server as suggested and make sure it is started.

Then you could try [EMS SQL Manager for InterBase/Firebird Freeware](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/ibfb/manager) that has a nice GUI and it can list/browse/edit all the tables/procedure/triggers/etc that the database may contain.

In EMS, first register a host (localhost) - push the "Detect Automatically" button to detect the Firebird server previously installed. For the connection settings, the default username is **SYSDBA**, password **masterkey** for the Firebird server.

Next step, register the database by providing the path to it.